# How to link to Avatar image in BlueSpice MediaWiki of fixed size?

Tags: html, css, mediawiki

The BlueSpice MediaWiki adds a profile picture that a user can set for themselves or take an automatically generated one.  These images are visible on pages to see who has edited or viewed a page recently. I'd like to include the pictures in other places, such as a list of people and phone numbers to include their pictures too.

Looking at the generated html, I see how the image comes in to those places:

```
<img alt="WilliamKF"
       src="/index.php?action=ajax&amp;title=-&amp;rs=SecureFileStore::getFile&amp;f=/bluespice/Avatars/thumb/BS_avatar_3.png/40px-BS_avatar_3.png"
       width="40"
       height="40"
  />
```

The image path is relative to the root of public_html on the server.  How can I add MediaWiki syntax markup to include an image in a wiki web page?  I tried enabling `$wgAllowExternalImages = true;` in the PHP and used a raw path in the wiki:

```
http://wiki.domain.com/index.php?action=ajax&title=-&rs=SecureFileStore::getFile&f=/bluespice/Avatars/BS_avatar_3.png
```

But that gives me a full sized image instead of a thumb that is 40x40, so how can I add more wiki markup syntax to limit the size? I tried wrapping `<div style="height: 32px; width: 32px;">` but that only caused the text to overlap the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thumbnail is not produced by the BlueSpice extension but by [thumb.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Thumb.php).

Your example has `f=/bluespice/Avatars/thumb/BS_avatar_3.png/40px-BS_avatar_3.png`, just replace `40px-` with `32px-`.